# git pull master: Error: Repository not found

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am not able to fetch from a private remote  repo, created by myself, to local.

Steps taken:

1. Generated SSH key. Added it to local SSH agent.
2. Verify SSH key is added with `ssh-add -l -E md5`
3. Add SSH public key through Github interface.
4. Add SSH URL with `git remote set-url {aliasName} {SSH url}`
5. attempt `git pull alias` on master. also try `git fetch alias`

In both instances I see this in terminal:

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I can also confirm the repo is there and has a master branch. What else could be the issue?

[image: cli output]

- Image is incorrect, I meant to say I added its public key to github.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your key is recognized:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

Then try:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'

git ls-remote git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>
```

That will give you an idea as to *where* the remote repository access fails.